# How to use the agg method of Spark KeyValueGroupedDataset?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We have some code like this:

```
// think of class A as a table with two columns
case class A(property1: String, property2: Long)

// class B adds a column to class A
case class B(property1: String, property2: Long, property3: String)

df.as[A].map[B](a => {
      val my_udf = // some code here which creates a user defined function
      new B(a.property1, a.property2, my_udf(a))
    })
```

where df is a DataFrame. next we want to create a dataset of type C

```
// we want to group objects of type B by properties 1 and 3 and compute the average of property2 and also want to store a count
case class C(property1: String, property3: String, average: Long, count: Long)
```

which we would have created in sql like this

```
select property1, property3, avg(property2), count(*) from B group by property1, property3
```

How can we do this in spark? we are trying to use the groupByKey that gives a [KeyValueGroupedDataSet](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/KeyValueGroupedDataset.html) together with [agg](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/KeyValueGroupedDataset.html#agg(org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn)) but unable to get it to work. Can't figure out how to use [agg](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/KeyValueGroupedDataset.html#agg(org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a dataset of type C called `ds_c`, then you can do (use `groupBy.agg`):

```
ds_c.groupBy("property1", "property3").agg(count($"property2").as("count"), 
                                           avg($"property2").as("mean"))
```

Comment: few issues 1. i don't see any count and avg keywords. they give me unrecognized keyword error by compiler 2. second how do we name columns of our dataset so that this code can work?

Comment: `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` may be necessary to get those functions in scope.

Comment: You can check [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) for all the common column functions. If you want to rename your data frame, you can use `withColumnRenamed(old name, new name)`.