# How to use agg() on a KeyValueGroupedDataset and remain Typesafe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I know that this question was posted here before but the answers weren't satisfiying for my case.

[How to use the agg method of Spark KeyValueGroupedDataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44014151/how-to-use-the-agg-method-of-spark-keyvaluegroupeddataset)

Actually the question posted here is not in line with the given content as it circles around a Dataset and its group() function and NOT a KeyValueGroupedDataset.

I am trying to work with case classes and stay typesafe. So in the above case the answers were not type safe and using sql statements on a Dataframe which is easlily recognizable by the given column names as string parameter.

What I am trying to achieve is this here:

```
    val r = dsResult1.groupByKey(r => r.Id)  // r is a KeyValueGroupedDataset
    r.agg   // ??? I don't know how to call this method and couldn't find any examples
```

This is the scaladoc : http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/KeyValueGroupedDataset.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [Aggregator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Aggregator.html) to stay type-safe.

Let's say we have a data class

```scala
case class A(id: Long, text: String)
```

with the data

```scala
val dsA: Dataset[A] = Seq(A(1, "one"), A(2, "two"), A(3, "three"), A(3, "THREE")).toDS()
//+---+-----+
//| id| text|
//+---+-----+
//|  1|  one|
//|  2|  two|
//|  3|three|
//|  3|THREE|
//+---+-----+
```

and we want to group the data by `id` while combining the `text`s of each `id`.

```scala
val kvgds: KeyValueGroupedDataset[Long, A] = dsA.groupByKey(a => a.id)

val myAggregateFunction: Aggregator[A, A, A] = new Aggregator[A, A, A] {
  def zero: A = A(-1, "")
  def reduce(a: A, b: A): A = if (b.equals(zero)) a else if (a.equals(zero)) b
                              else A(a.id, a.text + "+" + b.text)
  def merge(a: A, b: A): A = reduce(a, b)
  def finish(r: A): A = r
  def bufferEncoder: Encoder[A] = dsA.encoder
  def outputEncoder: Encoder[A] = dsA.encoder
}

val result: Dataset[(Long,A)] = kvgds.agg(myAggregateFunction.toColumn.name("result"))
```

All operations are type-safe and the result is a dataset with type `[(Long,A)]` and the contents

```
+---+----------------+
|key|          result|
+---+----------------+
|  1|        [1, one]|
|  3|[3, three+THREE]|
|  2|        [2, two]|
+---+----------------+
```

Comment: interesting, but too low level for my taste Despite the fact that I would have to come up  with (or look up) reduce functions for average, median, etc. by myself. But thanks for the solution.

Comment: Hi Werner, still finding this approach promising because I really want to preserve type safety throughout my code. My question to you: the answer directly addresses my case class. Do you have something on hand which would be more general. I am thinking of a generic class "MyAggregation[A,B] with A = any case class and B = implicit type class "MyAggProperty" which has the structure to be reduced. Kind Regards Sven

Comment: @Sven I am not really sure if I understand your comment. The `Aggregator` class is already generic. You could alter my answer by replacing the third type parameter (the output class) by let's say `B`, but you would have to provide appropriate `reduce` and `merge` functions. I think it would be difficult to infer these functions just by looking at the structure of `B`.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking way too complicated. I was looking for a more general solution as I have many Avg aggregations and I thought that I would have to implement them for each value to be calculated. Looks like I need to implement reduce and merge where I could then call my (base) implementation of average. So only one average function to be implemented and when I need I can override the base function. Thanks Walter

Answer (score 0):

Good lord. As of Spark 3.0.0 typed aggregates are not supported anymore and one should use the untyped aggregate functions instead :-( So I am going from typed to untyped, what the... Or are there other approaches to stay type safe.

Comment: take a look to https://github.com/typelevel/frameless